# The subquery returned more than one value. TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, name VARCHAR(30),
percent_part FLOAT, sales FLOAT, sum_bonus DECIMAL);

CREATE TRIGGER TRcointingBonus ON sales 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS BEGIN

DECLARE @sum_bonus FLOAT;
SELECT @sum_bonus = (SELECT ((sales / 100) * percent_part) FROM  sales);
UPDATE sales SET sum_bonus = @sum_bonus

END;

INSERT INTO sales VALUES('staff1', 7.0, 7088, 1);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES('staff2', 3.5, 20590, 1);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES('staff3', 10.5, 6089, 1);

UPDATE sales SET sales = 7088 WHERE id=1;
```

I create a table and a trigger, and for each UPATE operation, there will be calculations in each row of sum_bonus.

The problem is in

```
DECLARE @sum_bonus FLOAT;
SELECT @sum_bonus = (SELECT ((sales / 100) * percent_part) FROM sales);
```

If remove `FROM sales` then writing to the variable will not be possible. Can explain what is the reason and how to solve this problem without abandoning the variable?

Comment: Are you sure you want to read all rows from the table, calcualate an overall bonus and then update all rows in the table? Don't you rather want to work with/on the updated row? The old value is in `deleted.sales` / `deleted.percent_part`, the new one in `inserted.sales` / `inserted.percent_part`. However, it seems you are trying to do something here that you shouldn't do. Are you just trying to calculate a bonus for the row based on the row's values? Then you may want a mere computed column.

Comment: Don't abuse a trigger for a simple calculation. The calculation only takes values from columns of the same table, so there is no need for a trigger. Just do the calculation within your update command. Or let the application calculate it and just write the result in the update command.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner If I write `UPDATE sales SET sum_bonus = (SELECT (sales / 100) * procent)` everything works without errors, my question is why `FROM sales` breaks the query. I tried to create another table, the same query didn't work either

Comment: Well, `UPDATE sales SET sum_bonus = (SELECT (sales / 100) * procent)` is the same as `UPDATE sales SET sum_bonus = sales / 100 * procent`. Per row you are updating, you select its values, but you don't need a pseudo subquery for this, you can access the values directly. With `(SELECT ((sales / 100) * percent_part) FROM sales)` you select as many rows as are in the sales table. This may be 100 rows for instance. You cannot assign 100 values to a single float variable of course.

Comment: Don't use FLOAT for monetary data. https://blog.greglow.com/2018/01/15/sql-newbie-mistake-1-using-float-instead-decimal/

Answer (score 2):

Your actual error is very clear, your subquery returns more than one value. If you take your sample data, and run your subquery on it's own:

```
SELECT ((sales / 100) * percent_part) 
FROM  sales
```

You get 3 values:

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 496.16 |
| 720.65 |
| 639.345 |

You are then trying to assign this to a single decimal variable:

```
DECLARE @sum_bonus FLOAT;
SELECT @sum_bonus = (SELECT ((sales / 100) * percent_part) FROM sales);
```

So SQL Server has no idea which of the 3 values you are expecting to be stored, so throws an error - clearly telling you that the subquery can only return one row to avoid ambiguity.

To avoid the error change your subquery to return one row.

With that being said your trigger is massively flawed, it updates the entire table every time as it has no reference to either the `inserted` or `deleted` memory resident pseudo tables, and as above the value it is trying to update the entire table with doesn't really make sense either.

What you are trying to achieve can be done very simply with a [Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16), so your create table becomes something like:

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    name VARCHAR(30),
    percent_part FLOAT, 
    sales FLOAT, 
    sum_bonus AS (sales * percent_part / 100)
);
```

There's no need to store `sum_bonus` and use any kind of code to update it when underlying values change, just store the expression and calculate it as and when you need it.

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nXYOVXZk)**

**ADDENDUM**

To answer a question you have asked in the comments as to why this works:

```
UPDATE sales SET sum_bonus = (SELECT (sales / 100) * procent)
```

But adding `FROM sales` breaks the query - It is because adding `FROM Sales` fundamentally changes the query from just superfluous use of parenthesis and `SELECT`, to a subquery. The former is equivalent to simply:

```
UPDATE sales SET sum_bonus = sales / 100 * percent
```

i.e. `sales` and `percent` are references to columns from the instance of the `sales` being updated. By adding `FROM sales` you introduce a further instance of the `sales` table, and the two columns then become references to that. With no link to the instance being updated you end up with multiple rows in the subquery, and hence your error.

Comment: You are guessing that they just want to calculate a bonus for a row based on the row's values. This may or may not be correct. (I have my doubts, because the vaiable is called sum_bonus and not just bonus, so they may have some aggregation in mind.) Anyway, you are properly addressing the issues and questions, and I consider this a good answer, no matter whether the OP is looking for a mere computed column or not :-)